# How to query with graphene

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, graphene-python

I have a `query` as follows:

```
class MakeObj(graphene.ObjectType):
    id = graphene.Int()       
    name = graphene.String()     


class Query(object):
    makes = graphene.List(MakeObj)


    def resolve_makes(self, info, **kwargs):
        makes = get_makes(3)
        print(makes)
        return makes
```

In `print('makes')` the result is fine. I get something as follows:

```
[{'id': 212, 'name': 'ABARTH'}, {'id': 143, 'name': 'AIXAM'}, ....]
```

I want to return that to the frontend where I have the next code:

```
const GET_MAKES = gql`
query Makes {
  makes {
    id
    name
  }
}`;

class Makes extends Component {


    render() {
        const {loading, data: {makes}} = this.props;
        return (...)
     }
}

export default withQuery({query: GET_MAKES})(Makes);
```

The `withQuery` is an high order component and it does what it needs to be done. There are no problems.

But in the result, thus `this.props.data.makes` I get all null values, something as follows:

[image]

Any idea?